# Installing pyTorch / Torch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to install PyTorch / torch on pyCharm Community edition. It gave the following error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\joshu\uiuc\research\ai sound-20210814t005717z-001\ai sound\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c
> 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-ygcl9r4a\pytorch_62f432ab0d344f46a572a5a74f2b015b\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-ygcl9r4a\pytorch_62f432ab0d344f46a572a5a74f2b015b\setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-5cueumzp\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\joshu\uiuc\research\ai sound-20210814t005717z-001\ai
> sound\venv\include\site\python3.8\pytorch'
> cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-ygcl9r4a\pytorch_62f432ab0d344f46a572a5a74f2b015b
> Complete output (5 lines):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-ygcl9r4a\pytorch_62f432ab0d344f46a572a5a74f2b015b\setup.py",
> line 11, in 
> raise Exception(message)
> Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"

sorry that this is a noob question, but help is appreciated :)

Comment: **Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"** - Always read the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`torch` is the name of the package, not `pytorch`.

Type the following in your terminal.

```
pip install torch
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still throws that same error.

Comment: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\joshu\uiuc\programming\googlecodingchallengef\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\P
ublic\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-eaoqih98\\torch_72a15b601ea847e8af7a580a77c3f84d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-eaoqi
h98\\torch_72a15b601ea847e8af7a580a77c3f84d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO